# Cannot compile royale app using Crux: Could not find file for class: mx.rpc.AsyncToken

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, apache-royale, swiz

I'm creating a hello world type of application using Royale 0.9.6 and Crux. It's my first time trying out Crux and I've been using the examples provided within the Royale sdk to move forward. Unfortunately after setting up everything the compilation fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find JavaScript filePath for class: mx.rpc.AsyncToken org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.addDeps(GoogDepsWriter.java:643)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.addDeps(GoogDepsWriter.java:672)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.addDeps(GoogDepsWriter.java:672)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.addDeps(GoogDepsWriter.java:672)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.addDeps(GoogDepsWriter.java:672)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.buildDB(GoogDepsWriter.java:325)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.graph.GoogDepsWriter.getListOfFiles(GoogDepsWriter.java:113)org.apache.royale.compiler.internal.codegen.mxml.royale.MXMLRoyalePublisher.publish(MXMLRoyalePublisher.java:446)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSCRoyale.compile(MXMLJSCRoyale.java:441)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSCRoyale._mainNoExit(MXMLJSCRoyale.java:265)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSCRoyale.mainNoExit(MXMLJSCRoyale.java:222)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSC._mainNoExit(MXMLJSC.java:369)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSC.mainNoExit(MXMLJSC.java:304)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSC.staticMainNoExit(MXMLJSC.java:262)org.apache.royale.compiler.clients.MXMLJSC.main(MXMLJSC.java:244)
```

Then there are multiple error lines saying that multiple "mx.rpc" classes on which Crux depend cannot be found.

I'm wondering if I'm missing an import or something but I can't figure it out.

Thank you,

---

EDIT: Here are some simple steps to reproduce:

- Open Moonshine
- File > New > Royale Browser Project
- Type any project name and create the project
- Compile (CTRL + J): compilation successful
- Open the main mxml file src/[appname].mxml
- Add `xmlns:crux="library://ns.apache.org/royale/crux"` to the `<js:Application>` opening tag.
- Add the following: `<j:beads>
  <crux:Crux>
  </crux:Crux>
  </j:beads>`
- Compile (CTRL + J): compilation fails as described above.

[image: Minimal Crux Implementation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked into Moonshine IDE project files in [examples](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/tree/develop/examples/crux) available in Royale repository. They were broken - I have fixed them so you can wait for [Nightly build](http://apacheroyaleci2.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/job/royale-asjs_jsonly/287/) and download new SDK along with examples or just use checkout source code.

When you open any of those examples, right click in Moonshine choosing Settings and you should check Build Options - There will be many additional compiler parameters, but in your case probably it is enough if you put in "Additional Compiler Options" `+configname=flex`

Comment: Thank you Piotr, `+configname=flex` did the trick even with my current SDK but I downloaded the nightly build anyway to get the fixed examples as well. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot it looks like you're using `<j:beads>` but haven't declared the `<j:>` namespace. Try using `<js:beads>` instead.

Comment: Well spotted! Unfortunately putting `<js:beads>` didn't change anything. Same error :(
I've also tried adding the j namespace `xmlns:j="library://ns.apache.org/royale/jewel"` but it doesn't change a thing...